# Select Data in SQL from No links between another table/column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

Table and (columns) in question are:

```
Attachment (att_id)

Assignment (att_id, ctg_id, and itm_id)
```

I have tried for several hours to try and call the data I am looking for but to avail. I can't figure out the logic behind it and it seems so simple.

I need to call all the rows in the Attachment Table where the att_id **is not** linked to a ctg_id **or** itm_id  in the Assignment table.

I make the join on att_id = att_id but that brings up all the rows in the Attachment table that **are** linked to a ctg_id or itm_id, when I need just the opposite.

Very Frustrating. Any advise/help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should select all rows in Attachment that are not referenced by att_id in Assignment.

```
SELECT *
FROM Attachment
WHERE att_id NOT IN (SELECT att_id FROM Assignment)
```

JOIN is typically used to find links, not to find non-links. WHERE x NOT IN ([blah]) is used to find missing links.

Comment: Wow, now I feel helpless! That worked as described. I was trying to do it in reverse I guess! Thanks for the logic behind it, I will note for the future.

Answer (score 2):

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is an easy way to find non-matches:

```
select at.*
from Attachment at
left outer join Assignment as on at.att_id = as.att_id
where as.att_id is null
```

Comment: This worked as well! Thanks for showing me more logic behind different ways of executing this call!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a [Left Anti Semi Join](http://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/).

```
SELECT *
FROM Attachment
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Assignment
                  WHERE Attachment.att_id = Assignment.att_id)
```

It's also a bit more efficient than using a regular left outer join, though SQL server will often be smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from attachment a 
left join assignment a2
where a2.ctg_id is null or a2.itm_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try an alternate just so the correlated sub-query doesn't slow you down.

```
create table Attachment (att_id int)
create table Assignment ( att_id int, ctg_id int, itm_id int)
insert into Attachment values( 100)
insert into Attachment values( 350)
insert into Attachment values( 7)
insert into Attachment values( 99)

insert into Assignment values ( 100,1,1)
insert into Assignment values ( 7,2,2)

--SELECT *
--FROM Attachment
--WHERE att_id NOT IN (SELECT att_id FROM Assignment)

SELECT ATT.*
FROM Attachment ATT LEFT outer join Assignment ASI on ATT.att_id = ASI.att_id
WHERE ISNULL(ASI.att_id,-1)=-1

drop table Attachment
drop table assignment
```

edit: LOL - as I typed this up two more of the same answers came in. Oh well.